# Function that capitalises the first letter of each word in a sentance

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I made a function which make an array from a string, then capitalize first letter of every word but then im trying to make string of it with a join() function but it doesnt work. So the problem is to that join() method doesnt work so it will not convert array to a string

```
function titleCase(string) {
  const arr = string.split(' ')
  return arr.map(item => {
    const newArray = item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)
    return newArray.join('-')

  })
}
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Please don't expect us to debug your code. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Then find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what it is supposed to be & say why. (Debugging fundamantal.)

Comment: join() method. So i cant make a string from an array

Comment: Your `.join` call is at the wrong place, move it one line below and it will work. Should be return `arr.map(..yourCodeHere).join(' ')`

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```js
function ucFirst(string){
  return string.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()+string.slice(1);
}
function ucFirstSentence(sentences){
  const all = sentences.match(/.+?(\.|\!|\?)(\s+|$)/g);
  for(let i=0,l=all.length; i<l; i++){
    all[i] = ucFirst(all[i].trim());
  }
  return all.join(' ');
}
let uc = ucFirstSentence("this is just a test. i'm not really sure if it works, a.b. quite yet. i guess we'll see if this suits your needs!");
console.log(uc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your newArray variable in the callback function is actually not an array but a string of each element in arr array(with their first letter capitalized). You call join method on a string . You should actually assign arr.map method to a new variable and call the join method outside the arr.map method on this array.

```
function titleCase(string) {
  const arr = string.split(' ');
  const newArray = arr.map(item => {
    const eachWord = item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
    return eachWord;
  });
  return newArray.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

imo, giving variable proper names helps. you are close to a solution

```
function titleCase(string) {
  // split by space to get an array of word (string)
  return string.split(' ').map(word => {
     // uppercase first letter and append the rest
     return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  }).join(" "); // join words array with space
}
```